# Kubernetes error [::1]:6443: connect: cannot assign requested address

Tags: linux, api, kubernetes, kvm, kube-apiserver

I got the following error:

```
controller.go:228] unable to sync kubernetes service: Post "https://[::1]:6443/api/v1/namespaces": dial tcp [::1]:6443: connect: cannot assign requested address
```

I have the following warnings in my cluster kube (3x3 master/workers on prem (kvm)) with 3 etcd on masters.

```
kubectl get events --field-selector  type!=Normal -n kube-system
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON      OBJECT                             MESSAGE
3m25s       Warning   Unhealthy   pod/kube-apiserver-kube-master-1   Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
3m24s       Warning   Unhealthy   pod/kube-apiserver-kube-master-2   Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
3m25s       Warning   Unhealthy   pod/kube-apiserver-kube-master-2   Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
3m27s       Warning   Unhealthy   pod/kube-apiserver-kube-master-3   Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
17m         Warning   Unhealthy   pod/kube-apiserver-kube-master-3   Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
```

This error not affect my cluster or my servicies in any form. It's appear from the begining. How do I solve? :D

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Error.
My CoWorker deactivated IPv6 (to try something..) and Kubernetes tried to use IPv6.

After rebooting my Master, IPv6 came back and it worked again.

I searched for a bit and found this article: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/12/08/dual-stack-networking-ga/ which basically says you can set `ipFamilyPolicy` to one of three options:

- SingleStack
- PreferDualStack
- RequireDualStack

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you are assigning [::1] address to endpoints..

> The endpoint IPs must not be: loopback (127.0.0.0/8 for IPv4, ::1/128
> for IPv6), or link-local (169.254.0.0/16 and 224.0.0.0/24 for IPv4,
> fe80::/64 for IPv6).

[::1] Means 127.0.0.1 in ipv6 address.

Comment: I know ... I use default deploy from kubespray and this is what I found. I think is miss configuration??